# Increasing vs decreasing functions

Tags: functions, terminology, order-theory

Some of the literatures use increasing and nondecreasing interchangeably. What can we say about functions that are neither increasing nor decreasing?

Comment: they are constant

Comment: Yes, they are constants.

Comment: They are either constant (if they are continuous) or more pathological.  Consider, for example, the characteristic function of the rationals: $$\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$ This function is neither increasing nor decreasing on any interval.

Comment: When there is no increase or decrease it is a constant ... is not even a function.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to understand explanation:

Any graph where $y$ is affected by $x$ will either increase or decrease at various points, sometimes multiple times. E.g. $y=ax+b$ is strictly increasing if $a>0$ and strictly decreasing if $a<0$, whilst any curves will have points at which the curve increases or decreases. So the only way for a curve to be neither increasing nor decreasing is if $x$ doesn't affect it, or rather, where $y=c$ where $c$ is a constant.

Better explanation:

If a curve $y=f(x)$ is neither increasing nor decreasing, then $f'(x)\equiv0$ $ \forall x$. Integrating then tells us $f(x)\equiv\int(0)\equiv0+C=C$ (where $C$ is the constant of integration)

Comment: Thanks all I have got important concepts from you.